# Angular 4 : add new td to table with *ngif with modulo in an *ngfor

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm a beginner and I'm using Angular 4.3.2 in my project. 
I'm trying to make a table which looks like this : (I have 2 arrays : the legend is an enum, and I have items)

- EnumValue1  || item1 | item2 | item3 | item4
- EnumValue2  || item5 | item6 | item7 | item8
- EnumValue3  || item9 | item10| item11| item12
- EnumValue4  || item13| item14| item15| item16

I would like to iterate throw the items and say something like this to create new td : 
`*ngif="items.length%4==0`

I've this html code :

```
        <tr *ngFor="let enum of enums">
            <th>{{enum}}</th>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
                <td *ngIf="items.length%4==0">{{item .id}}</td>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>
```

But it displays nothing.

This code displays all my items at each rows :

```
            <tr *ngFor="let enum of enums">
                <th>{{enum}}</th>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
                    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                </ng-container>
            </tr>
```

I don't know how to proceed. I've tried to follow this example but I can't put two *ng in one tag : [example with angular JS 1.3](http://plnkr.co/edit/lVkfC5jI4YMtyXd5yN1d?p=preview)

Any help would be welcome.

Edit part  : describe arrays content--
My arrays look like this in my model.ts :

```
export enum enums{
    'EnumValue1',
    'EnumValue2',
    'EnumValue3 ',
    'EnumValue4 '
}
```

In my component, I retrieve my enum :

```
keys(): Array<string> {
    const keys = Object.keys(enums);
    return keys.slice(keys.length / 2);
}
```

My items are an attribute of an object, in my component it looks like that :

```
export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    items: Item[];
    object: Object;

    [...constructor]

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = this.object.items;
    }
}
```

My object is defined when a pop up is opened in order to edit this object.

--end edit

Comment: Can you provide us with more details about your arrays , it would be easier to debug if you could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is this `items.slice(i*4 , (i+1)*4)` :

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let enum of enums;let i = index;">
      <th>{{enum}}</th>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items.slice(i*4 , (i+1)*4)">
          <td>{{item}}</td>
      </ng-container>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-array-chunk)**